# Are there some HLS & MPEG-DASH transcoder on the fly?

Tags: video-streaming, video-encoding, http-live-streaming, transcoding, mpeg-dash

Are there some free transcoders on the fly which can pack video into hls or mpeg-dash on the fly?
I don't want to use live streaming but I want to create vod streaming.